# Value for HADOOP_CONF_DIR from Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have setup a cluster(YARN) using Ambari with 3 VMs as hosts.

Where I can find the value for HADOOP_CONF_DIR ?

```
# Run on a YARN cluster
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=XXX
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master yarn-cluster \  # can also be `yarn-client` for client mode
  --executor-memory 20G \
  --num-executors 50 \
  /path/to/examples.jar \
  1000
```

Comment: I don't know much about Spark. But, can't you find out the HADOOP_CONF_DIR from the HADOOP_HOME? Usually HADOOP_CONF_DIR is "$HADOOP_HOME\etc\hadoop"

Answer (score 15):

Install Hadoop as well. In my case I've installed it in /usr/local/hadoop

Setup Hadoop Environment Variables

```
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop
```

Then set the conf directory

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/etc/hadoop
```

Answer (score 4):

From `/etc/spark/conf/spark-env.sh`:

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_CONF_DIR:-/etc/hadoop/conf}
```

Comment: Thank you. In my case Spark is running in a cluster. And its template I can see export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_CONF_DIR:-{{hadoop_conf_dir}}}