# What is the difference between Spark Standalone, YARN and local mode?

Tags: apache-spark

**Spark Standalone:**

In this mode I realized that you run your Master and worker nodes on your local machine.

Does that mean you have an instance of YARN running on my local machine? Since when I installed Spark it came with Hadoop and usually YARN also gets shipped with Hadoop as well correct? And in this mode I can essentially simulate a smaller version of a full blown cluster.

**Spark Local Mode:**

This is the part I am also confused on. To run it in this mode I do `val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]")`.

In this mode, it doesn't use any type of resource manager (like YARN) correct? Like it simply just runs the Spark Job in the number of threads which you provide to `"local[2]"\`?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You are getting confused with Hadoop YARN and Spark.

> YARN is a software rewrite that decouples MapReduce's resource
>   management and scheduling capabilities from the data processing
>   component, enabling Hadoop to support more varied processing
>   approaches and a broader array of applications.

With the introduction of YARN, Hadoop has opened to run other applications on the platform.

> In short YARN is "Pluggable Data Parallel framework".

Apache Spark

> Apache spark is a Batch interactive Streaming Framework. Spark has a
>   "pluggable persistent store". Spark can run with any persistence layer.

For spark to run it needs resources. In standalone mode you start workers and spark master and persistence layer can be any - HDFS, FileSystem, cassandra etc. In YARN mode you are asking YARN-Hadoop cluster to manage the resource allocation and book keeping.

When you use master as `local[2]` you request Spark to use 2 core's and run the driver and workers in the same JVM. In local mode all spark job related tasks run in the same JVM.

So the only difference between Standalone and local mode is that in Standalone you are defining "containers" for the worker and spark master to run in your machine (so you can have 2 workers and your tasks can be distributed in the JVM of those two workers?) but in local mode you are just running everything in the same JVM in your local machine.

Comment: Also if I submit my Spark job to a YARN cluster (Using spark submit from my local machine), how does the SparkContext Object know where the Hadoop cluster is to connect to?

Comment: CurrentIy, I use Spark-submit and specify `--deploy-mode` as `cluster`. But how does the SparkContext know where the Hadoop cluster is to run the spark applications on the HDFS data nodes? Is there some configuration for Spark that specifies where the Hadoop cluster is and whenever you instantiate an instance of SparkContext it knows where the cluster is because of that configuration file?

Comment: Ensure that HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR points to the directory which contains the (client side) configuration files for the Hadoop cluster. These configs are used to write to HDFS and connect to the YARN ResourceManager. The configuration contained in this directory will be distributed to the YARN cluster so that all containers used by the application use the same configuration . https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34333384/value-for-hadoop-conf-dir-from-cluster

Answer (score 34):

Local mode
Think of local mode as executing a program on your laptop using single JVM. It can be java, scala or python program where you have defined & used spark context object, imported spark libraries and processed data residing in your system.

YARN
In reality Spark programs are meant to process data stored across machines. Executors process data stored on these machines. We need a utility to monitor executors and manage resources on these machines( clusters). Hadoop has its own resources manager for this purpose. So when you run spark program on HDFS you can leverage hadoop's resource manger utility i.e. yarn. Hadoop properties is obtained from ‘HADOOP_CONF_DIR’ set inside spark-env.sh  or bash_profile

Spark Standalone
Spark distribution comes with its own resource manager also. When your program uses spark's resource manager, execution mode is called Standalone. Moreover, Spark allows us to create distributed master-slave architecture, by configuring properties file under $SPARK_HOME/conf directory. By Default it is set as single node cluster just like hadoop's psudo-distribution-mode.

Comment: Is Local Mode the only one in which you don't need to rely on a Spark installation? meaning, in local mode you can just use the Spark jars and don't need to submit to a cluster. Is that also possible in Standalone mode?

Comment: In Standalone mode we submit to cluster and specify spark master url  in  --master option

Comment: Can we start the cluster from jars and imports rather than install spark, for a Standalone run?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to start with JVMs.

So JVM is something that is installed in your system. It is nothing but an interpreter and it is accompanied with some mandatory libraries. So JVM + libraries  = JRE.

Firstly any no of JVMs can be formed in your system. i.e. There can be many JVMs with their own resources allocated e.g. memory, cores etecetra. But they all share the interpreter, libraries because there is only one copy of them.

Now, in local mode only one JVM takes care of the processing only one machine is used. You can specify how many cores you need , which will in turn become the cores of that JVM. Since you have n number of cores assigned to local mode JVM. You can do partitioning as well here. Maximum partition you can do to the data is no of cores, otherwise there wont be any advantage.

Now in Standalone mode. You will create not one JVM but many. And the spark's own ResourceManager will handle the processing between these JVMs. Since there are multiple JVMs you can have these JVMs in different machines as well. It is a cluster mode.

In cluster mode we use third party resouce managers like YARN/Mesos. You can do same thing as standalone mode.

Comment: IMHO, best answer for developers. Could you provide more details and reasons for "You can do partitioning as well here. Maximum partition you can do to the data is no of cores, otherwise there wont be any advantage." ?