# Difference between spark standalone and local mode?

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, mode

**What is the difference between Spark standalone and Local mode?**

Comment: please look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40013023/647053) This question is possible duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Spark Standalone, YARN and local mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012093/what-is-the-difference-between-spark-standalone-yarn-and-local-mode)

Comment: Yes question is duplicate but answer is not. That answer was  not clear to me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spark standalone is a resource manager which can work on a cluster. It is simply the built in resource manager as opposed to an external one like yarn.

Spark local runs without any resource manager, everything runs in a single jvm (you can decide the number of threads). This is aimed for testing locally.

Comment: In addition to that.. you can use local mode for the development purpose where you do not want to eat up the cluster resources and looking for the faster execution time during unit testing or debugging.