# Why does switching conda environments eliminate HADOOP_CONF_DIR?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, anaconda, hadoop-yarn

I have a strange environment problem. I have two conda environments `base` and `rnn`. When I type in `pyspark --master yarn` while in the `base` environment, the interactive shell comes up successful and I can use the YARN web UI to see that the PySpark shell has been submitted to YARN.

However, when I type in `source activate rnn` and followed by `pyspark --master yarn`, I see the following exception thrown.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: When running with
>   master 'yarn' either HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR must be set in
>   the environment.
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.validateSubmitArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:286)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.validateArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:246)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:119)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:129)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

If switch back to the `base` conda environment, and type in `printenv`, I do not see HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR either. I am confused as to where or how these environment variables are being set and why switching from one conda environment to another would result in the exception above. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Probably these variables are set inside scripts. In your base conda env the scripts are correct, while in another - are not.

Comment: Do you have an intuition on which scripts or directory? I don't know enough about the internals of conda to pick a location.

Comment: This does not happen in conda. It happens in spark scripts. Conda only changes paths to scripts that are used. For example in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34333384/value-for-hadoop-conf-dir-from-cluster) answer there is a path to one script.